# How to pass additional parameter to jQuery $.ajax() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using following ajax utility function to make requests

```
function ajaxHandler(url, data)
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                reject(error);
            },


        });
    })

}
```

The default settings works great most of the time, but there are quite a few cases where I would like pass additional parameters like `processData` and `contentType`. How can pass `processData` and `contentType` for such cases ?

Comment: I do not see `processData` variable in your code. Also  `options` is not used.

Comment: so extend an object,

Comment: You've got an `options` object but you're not using it?

Comment: MaxZoom , epascarello - I want to use the default for `processData` and `contentType`. However, there are few cases where I have to override default values, for instance while uploading image. Did you get my point ?

Comment: @axli How to use it ?

Comment: As a side note you dont need to create a Promise, $.ajax already returns a promise object so just return that

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks, I didn't know that ?

Comment: @Cody yes I understand, hence why I suggested extend. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `options` is the object you want to pass in;  moving the config object out of the function is about the cleanest. Then use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to update the defaults

```
function ajaxHandler(url, data, options) {

  var config = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
  }

  if (options && $.type(options) == 'object') {
    $.extend(config, options);
  }

  return $.ajax(config)// add a global error handler if desired
}
```

Usage :

```
ajaxHandler('path/to/server', {foo:'bar'), {type:'GET'})
  .then(function(data){
     console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(){// or `catch` in jQuery version >=3
     // handle error
  })
```

Note that `$.ajax` returns a *"thenable"* promise so using `new Promise` is an anti-pattern. See [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: Don't we need to catch the error in `ajaxHandler()` function after `.then()` ?

Comment: All depends how you want to set it up ...with a global error handler or one per use

Comment: Also note that `$.post` , `$.get`  & `$.getJSON` are also very useful shortcuts that don't require much setup

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it right, if you like to add and override settings of the object you can use $.extend

```
function ajaxHandler(url, data, extraSettings)
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax($.extend({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                reject(error);
            },


        }, extraSettings));
    })

}
```

This way $.extend(obj1, obj2) returns obj1 adding or overwriting properties of obj2.

you can use it like:
    ajaxHanler("url", "data", { contentType: "text/plain" });